# Merge Files and Prepend Filename and Directory

Tags: linux, merge, grep

I need to merge files in a directory and include the directory, filename, and line number in each line of the output. I've found many helpful posts about including the filename and line number but not the directory name. Grep -n gets line numbers and I've seen some find commands that get some of the other parts but I can't seem to pull them all together. (I'm using Ubuntu for all of the data processing.)

Imagine two files in directory named "8". (Each directory in the data I have is a number. The data were provided that way.)

file1.txt

> John
> Paul
> George
> Ringo

file2.txt

> Mick
> Keef
> Bill
> Brian
> Charlie

The output should look like this:

> 8:file1.txt:1:John
> 8:file1.txt:2:Paul
> 8:file1.txt:3:George
> 8:file1.txt:4:Ringo
> 8:file2.txt:1:Mick
> 8:file2.txt:2:Keef
> 8:file2.txt:3:Bill
> 8:file2.txt:4:Brian
> 8:file2.txt:5:Charlie

The separators don't have to be colons.  Tabs would work just fine.

Thanks much!

Comment: This is better suited to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Here's a question that there might help you out: http://superuser.com/questions/162620/how-to-add-prefix-suffix-to-each-line-of-a-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just one directory level deep you could try something like so. We go into each directory, print each line with its number and then append the directory name to the front with sed:

```
$ for x in `ls`; do
   (cd $x  ; grep -n . *) | sed -e 's/^/'$x:'/g'
 done

1:c.txt:2:B
1:c.txt:3:C
2:a.txt:1:A
2:a.txt:2:B
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  That works quite well.  On interesting thing is that if I direct the output to a file in one of those folders then it becomes an infinite loop. (I should have known that...) Once I directed the output to a file outside of the folder containing the data it worked just fine.

Comment: Paul, quick question if you don't mind.  I have almost 2 million files in many folders and I'm getting a "Argument list too long" error.  I've tried some variations of xargs but not getting the right results.  How can I accomplish this with the code you've provided?

Comment: where are you trying the xargs? I suspect it could be needed in both the `ls` and in the `grep -n ...`

Comment: After a lot of searching and testing it turns out the bottleneck was grep, not ls.  I found some information about using the -r option with grep, which traverses directories rather than naming the files within them.  So simplifying Paul's code to `for x in \`ls\`; do (grep -nr . $x);  done` did the trick.  The directory is automatically printed at the start of each line, which mean sed isn't needed. Thanks, Paul, for getting me started down the right path.